# some movie, book and game title have a title. And sequels often have the title a number and some more words what are the extra words called?

Tags: titles

The best example would probably be most of the star wars movie titles
phantom menace, attack of the clones, revenge of the sith, return of the jedi, rogue one, empire strikes back, and the last jedi just to name a few.

The termninator movie series comes to mind also. the title have 2 parts instead of 3 like start wars Terminator 2: judgement day, Terminator 3 rise of the machines.

Lastly  have to mention what i seen that made me post this question the Ace combat video game series. Yes I am a fan of the series and i seen a youtube video for ace combat 7 with the proper title in the thumbnail. but the title mentioned the "extra words" from Ace Combat 5 title

Ace Combat 3: Electrosphere
Ace Combat 4: Shattered Skies
Ace Combat 5: The Unsung War
Ace Combat 6: Fires of Liberation
Ace Combat 7: Skies Unknown

what is the term for the second part of the title?

Comment: Please edit this post into standard written English. It is tantamount to illegible now.

Answer (score 2):

### Subtitle

While this term is often used for captions near the bottom of the screen in a movie, to assist the deaf or to provide a translation, it also means the secondary title of a book or movie. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subtitled), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle_(titling))

An example can be seen here from a website about publishing books: [Publishing Reviews](https://publishingreviews.wordpress.com/2013/04/18/how-to-come-up-with-a-subtitle-in-your-book/comment-page-1/)

Image from Molly Blaisdell[3](https://publishingreviews.wordpress.com/2013/04/18/how-to-come-up-with-a-subtitle-in-your-book/comment-page-1/)

[image]